# Где почитать или кто может рассказать что такое DataModel в jsf

Tags: java, jsf

Знакомая сдаёт экзамен и у неё такой вопрос  DataModel в jsf. С ним никогда не работал и прочитав доках, как понял объяснил, а препод ей сказал что чушь. Прошу помощи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исчерпывающим и достаточным для преподавателя должен быть [текст из официальной документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html).

> DataModel is an abstraction around arbitrary data binding technologies
>   that can be used to adapt a variety of data sources for use by
>   JavaServer Faces components that support per-row processing for their
>   child components.

Если для себя хочется более пространного объяснения с примером, то страницы с 209 по 216 учебника [Дэвида Гери и Кея Хорстманна "JavaServer Faces"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5807786/) таковое содержат.

Comment: Спасибо большое сейчас почитаю

Comment: Там просто экзамен и ему мало говорит

Comment: Соболезную, вам достался препод с причудами. Можно было бы удариться в объяснения, что сами создатели технологии считают это достаточным, но тогда шансов на сдачу нет. Надо выяснять, что он давал на лекциях. Фраза "А вы только это рассказывали, вот конспект" обладает более чудотворным эффектом.